# Finding interest Rate

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The following problem is what I have to answer, however, I do not know how to do it. Please show steps as it would help me understand how to do it and do my other problems similar to this one. I know how to do the original equation and find compounded interest but I do not know how to find the interest rate.

$A(t)=P(1+\frac{r}{n})^{nt} . $P=$20,000$, $t=30$ years $n$=quarterly $A(30)=400,000$ Find $r$ =? (interest rate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A = P\cdot (1 + \dfrac{r}{n})^{nt}$. With $A = 400,000$, $n = 4$, $t = 30$, $P = 20,000$. Then $400,000 = 20,000\cdot (1 + \dfrac{r}{4})^{4\cdot 30}$. So $1 + \dfrac{r}{4} = 20^{\frac{1}{120}} = 1.0253$. So $r = 4\cdot 0.0253 = 0.101$ or about ten percent.